# Is an integral of a bounded function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lipschitz-functions

I have the function $f$ that is Riemann-integrable in $[a,b]$. First, I need to prove that the function $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(x) dx$ is a Lipschitz function in $[a,b]$.

Second, supposing only that $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ (not necessarily Riemann-integrable anymore). Define $H(x)=\overline{\int_{a}^{x}} f(x) dx$. Prove H is a Lipschitz function in $[a,b]$.

Comment: This is not difficult and you should try it out instead of just posting problem statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann-integrable, then [it is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288750/showing-if-f-unbounded-then-f-is-not-riemann-integrable). That is, there exists $c>0$ with $|f(x)|\leq c$ for all $x$. Then, for $y\geq x$, 
$$
|F(y)-F(x)|=\left|\int_x^y f(x)\,dx\right|\leq\int_x^y|f(x)|\,dx\leq\int_x^y c\,dx=c(y-x). 
$$
For the case where $f$ is bounded, you play the same game as above, but now on the upper sums.